# How to compute area of each blob individually

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am attaching here an image for which I need to calculate number of blobs and compute area of each blob separately. I am using Matlab for doing this.

[image]

Black regions have index value '0' and white background have index value '1'

Thank you in advance. It would be great if some one helps me in doing this.

Comment: You might want to try `bwlabel` and `regionprops`.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is to find the number of *blobs*. For that, I'll rather use k-Means clustering. It will be too long to explain what the k-means clustering does, how does it work and so on, so I'll jump straight to the point: the k-Means algorithm groups *n* points into *k* groups (clusters). The result is a partitioned space: a given point cannot be in two clusters at the same time and a cluster is identified by its centroid (the mean point).

So let's import the image and find all `x` and `y` coordinates for black points: these are indeed the points we want to cluster.

```
I=imread('image.jpg');
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
[x,y]=find(BW==0);
```

Now it's time to trigger the k-Means algorithm in order to group such points. Since we don't know *k*, that is the number of blobs, we can perform some sort of bruteforce approach. We select some candidate values for *k* and apply k-Means clustering to all of these values. Later on, we select the best *k* by means of the Elbow Method: we plot the so-called Within Cluster Sum of Squares (that is the sum of all the distances between points and their respective centroid) and select the *k* value such that adding another cluster doesn't give much better modeling of the data.

```
for k=1:10
    [idx{k},C{k},sumd{k}] = kmeans([x y],k,'Replicates',20);
end
sumd=cellfun(@(x) sum(x(:)),sumd);
```

The code above performs the k-Means for *k* in range [1, 10]. Since in standard k-Means the first centroids are randomly selected amongst the points in our dataset (i.e. the black points), we repeat k-Means 20 times for each value of *k* and then the algorithm will automatically return the best results amongst the 20 repetitions. Such results are `idx` that is a vector of *n* points (where *n* is the number of black points) that contains in its j-th position the centroid ID for the j-th black point. `C` are the centroid coordinates and `sumd` is the sum of squares.

We then plot the sum of squares vs the *k* candidates:

```
figure(6);
plot(1:10,sumd,'*-');
```

and we obtain something like:
[image]

According to the Elbow Method explained above, 6 is the optimal number of clusters: indeed after 6 the plot tends to be rather horizontal.
So from the arrays above, we select the 6th element:

```
best_k=6;
best_idx=idx{best_k};
best_C=C{best_k};
```

and the returned clusters are

```
gscatter(x,y,best_idx); hold on;
plot(best_C(:,1),best_C(:,2),'xk','LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

*Note*: the image is rotated because `plot()` handles matrices (coordinates) differently with respect to `imshow()`. Also black-crossed points are the centroids for each cluster.

And finally by counting the number of points per cluster, we gather the area of the cluster itself (i.e. the blob):

```
for m=1:best_k
    Area(m)=sum(best_idx==m);
end


Area =

        1619          46         141         104         584         765
```

Obviously the i-th item in `Area` is the area of the i-th cluster, as reported by the legend.

*Further readings*
In this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) you can find some more details regarding the determination of the number of cluster (the "best *k*") in the k-Means algorithm. Amongst these methods you can find the Elbow Method as well. As @rayryeng correctly pointed out in the comments below, the Elbow plot is just an heuristic: in some datasets you cannot clearly spot a "knee" in the curve...we've been lucky though!
Last but not least, if you want to know more about the k-Means algorithm, please have a look at @rayryeng's answer linked below in the comments: it's a brilliantly detailed answer that not only describes the algorithm itself, but also talks about the repetitions I've set in the code, the initial centroid randomly selected and all these aspects I've been skipping in order to avoid an endless answer.

Comment: Not to be self-promoting, but a great explanation of k-means clustering can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691735/matlab-color-based-segmentation/25691983#25691983 - It serves as an introduction before I go into how it's used by the OP for colour image segmentation. I'm posting this here as you have mentioned that you are glossing over the details. The link I have serves as a more detailed description of the algorithm if it is desired to be explored.

Comment: @rayryeng, indeed. Sorry. I forgot to link some useful resources for the Elbow Method and the k-Means. I didn't talk about it myself to avoid an utterly verbose answer. I've been reading your post for the sake of curiosity, brilliantly detailed.

Comment: Thanks :) I've already upvoted your answer.  However, I would probably mention that the Elbow method is entirely a heuristic.  Not all data is suitable for the Elbow method... but in this case, it works just fine.